# Tooling API Composite Request

Tags: apex, tooling-api, httprequest

I'm trying to create multiple flexipage records from workbench using the tooling API but I'm getting a 404 error "Resource Not Found". I followed the following resource: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm

[image: POST Request From WorkBench]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Composite API for flexipages is not available and aren't exposed under `/tooling/composite/sobjects` endpoint.  The references to Flexipage have been removed and updated in newest [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm).  A patch update will be rolled out in coming days to update previous doc version.

Thanks

Comment: `/tooling/composite/sobjects` fails for more than just Flexipages.  Will the new doc update cover supported sobjects?

Comment: There is no specific update on objects since most of them aren't supported.

Comment: @Vinay what is the purpose of this endpoint if most objects aren't supported? Also that's not a valid reason not to document which ones are supported, even if it's just a few. Any info would be appreciated!