# Rest calls for Tooling API object with composite do not work

Tags: apex, rest-api, tooling-api, workbench

I'm trying to create multiple ApexClassMember records via REST Tooling API calls.

In official documentation they claim, that You can [Create Multiple Records with Fewer Round-Trips](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm)

However, in workbench such request returns error `"Service not found at: /services/data/v54.0/tooling/composite/sobjects"`
[image]

My request body

```
{
  "records": [
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "ApexClassMember"
  },
  "metadataContainerId": "1dc78000000Gt2nAAC",
  "contentEntityId": "01p78000000CxJ6AAK",
  "body": ""
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "ApexClassMember"
  },
  "metadataContainerId": "1dc78000000Gt2nAAC",
  "contentEntityId": "01p78000000Cw6zAAC",
  "body": ""
}]}
```

Moreover, record retrieval also does not work. It looks like the whole `/tooling/composite` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a doc bug - as it *seems* no tooling object supports it. It's sort-of mentioned in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354771/tooling-api-composite-request?noredirect=1&lq=1) - though it says "most objects" don't support it. Yet, I haven't seen an object work on that given endpoint: `composite/sobjects`.

For your situation, `ApexClassMember` is also not available in the REST API composite sobjects endpoint either - so it seems you have no option to bulkify your `POST` call.

For `GET`, you can use the [composite resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_requests_composite_composite.htm) (`services/data/v54.0/tooling/composite`) to do bulk queries on `ApexClassMember` - you can utilize the *query* endpoint or the Id of `ApexClassMember`

```json
{
   "allOrNone" : true,
   "compositeRequest" : [
       {
          "method": "GET",
          "referenceId": "queryWithApexClassMember",
          "url": "/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClassMember/400XXXXXXXXXXXX"
       },
       {
          "method": "GET",
          "referenceId": "query2",
          "url": "/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+ID+FROM+ApexClassMember"
       }
 
    ]
}
```

However, when you try to utilize `POST` on `ApexMemberClass` in the composite endpoint, you get the following message

```json
"body" : [ {
      "errorCode" : "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
      "message" : "HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,PATCH,DELETE"
    } ]
```

Testing various tooling objects (haven't tested all), they all seem to throw the same error as above.

Comment: A doc update would be much appreciated. As everyone knows, half the frustration is the docs being vague.

Comment: 100% agree. FWIW, there's a work item for it regarding updating the documentation.