# How to create multiple ApexClassMembers with one call?

Tags: apex, rest-api, tooling-api, post, httppost

According to **answer** to my previous [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371498/rest-calls-for-tooling-api-object-with-composite-do-not-work), Tooling API objects are not supported in `/composite` calls.

Is there a way to insert a large (*let's say 2000*) number of `ApexClassMembers` instead of iterating through the list and POSTing to `/services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClassMember/` for every element? Such approach will hit the limits immediately, therefore I consider it useless.

Comment: Are you trying to roll your own deployment tool? Seems like other tools might make more sense for the job here.

Comment: sfdx, metadata API both support up to 10k components. Why not use that?

Comment: I'm just trying to collect SymbolTable with method references for every class in org in order to detect unused methods just like here https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/02/02/spring-cleaning-apex-code-with-the-tooling-api/ but in Apex

Comment: @BartłomiejGóral Even I am trying to do the same. But seems like we can create only one ApexClassMember at a time through tooling request. Did you found an alternate option? Strange though - as per Andy's blog he was able to send multiple ApexClassMembers records through java client.